# Who did Shelah (Judah's son) marry?

Tags: genesis, numbers, marriage

In Genesis we learn that Judah's sons Er and Onan died, and both of them were married to Tamar. Because of their deaths (and involvement with the same woman, Tamar), Judah thinks that Tamar has something to do with them dying, and so refuses to give Shelah (his other son) to her as a husband.
So, Tamar disguises as a prostitute and conceives by Judah.

Does Tamar marry someone else after conceiving from Judah?
Does she eventually marry Judah's son, Shelah?

Because **Numbers 26:20** mentions descendants of Shelah, Judah's son, so this makes me wonder if he *did* eventually marry Tamar, since usually a deceased man who was childless would have his brother marry his wife to carry on the family line, as Onan did after Er died.

Even though the family line was carried on by Tamar conceiving from Judah, does this still suggest that Shelah married Tamar?

Comment: Kindly click [**here**](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4119/did-tamar-marry-a-third-time-and-if-so-whom) for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible does not give Shelah's wife's name (or maybe more accurately, the woman/women who bore him his children, since there is no details at all).

The explicit references to Tamar being the mother of Judah's children even beyond Genesis (Ruth 4:12, 1 Chr 2:4, Mt 1:3) and yet her name absent in relation to Shelah strongly hints that, as [Joseph's answer regarding Tamar investigates](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/4120/2070), Shelah did not marry Tamar.

However, the fact that Shelah did name a son of his Er (likely firstborn; 1 Chr 4:21) after his oldest brother who had first married Tamar (Gen 38:6), implies that in some way he wanted to still see his brother's name continued on, giving some form of a legacy, even though the Levirate marriage to Tamar had not come about (Gen 38:14).

Comment: Good concise (and correct) answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

The Bible does not mention his wife, only that he had children.